# How can I make Update() not spam?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public override void Update()
{
    if (x = 0)
    {
        LogToConsole("1");
    }
    if (x > 0)
    {
        LogToConsole("2");
    }
}
```

I have problems with this Script spamming the console. How can I make this only send the message once if it switches from `x = 0` to `x > 0` or the other way around instead of spamming it **30** times a second?

Comment: where is `x` defined?  Why are you attempting an assignment in the first conditional?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `x`? Why is this code in the `Update` function? Why isn't `x` a property that will `LogToConsole` when it changes?

Comment: Are you using a framework of some kind?  You marked `Update` with `override` which makes me suspect you are.  if yes please specify which framework as it affects the answer.

Comment: He's probably using unity3d

Comment: What is this [spamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming) you speak of?

Comment: `==` rather than `=` (given your code, as is, likely doesn't even compile).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Update`.

```
private int _myInt = 3;
public int MyInt {
    get { return _myInt; }
    set {
        if (_myInt != value) {
            Debug.Log("MyInt changed from "+_myInt+" to "+value);
            _myInt = value;
        }
    }
}

private void Start () {
    MyInt = 5;
    MyInt = 5;
    MyInt = 7;
    MyInt = 7;
}
```

---

```
MyInt changed from 3 to 5
MyInt changed from 5 to 7
```

Just add `string _lastLog`, and compared with the new is `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just track whatever value was last "logged" like this:

```
private int curLog = -1;

public override void Update()
{
    if (x == 0 && curLog != 1)
    {
        curLog = 1;
        LogToConsole("1");
    }
    else if (x > 0 && curLog != 2)
    {
        curLog = 2;
        LogToConsole("2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just track the changes in your variable `x`

```
private bool xStateChanged = false;
public override void Update()
{
    if(xStateChanged)
    {
        if(x == 0)
        {
            LogToConsole("1");
        }
        else if(x > 0)
        {
            LogToConsole("2");
        }
        xStateChanged = false;
    }
}
.
.
.
//Somewhere where you are changing the value of: x
private void ChangeValueOfX()
{
    x = 0;
    // Or you might change it to 
    x = 2; //Or Something higher then 0
    XStateChanged = true;
}
```

Now where you want to change the value of `x` you just have to set `xStateChanged` to `true` and `Update()` will call one of the `LogToConsole()` only once.